# Embedding font files into FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Im using FPDF to create dynamic PDF files, and Im using some new fonts to generate, the pdf files are fine for me, but it seems they are having font files into them, when I open the same documents on other machine text is giving different symbols which reflects lack of font support.
Can some one tell me how to embed the font files into PDF output files so it wont need any external font support in any computer?

Procedure I followed with FPDF is
->Got some font files which I want to use (.ttf files)
->Converted them into font.php and font.z files using font creator by FPDF(http://fpdf.fruit-lab.de/)
->Ive placed font.php and font.z files into font directory of FPDF
->Generated PDF files :(

My Guess
->Do I need to use font.afm files in processing? im not sure how this PDF file creation works and how to embed font files into output.

Comment: helpful question, even im looking answer for the same question:(

Comment: same question any luck?

Comment: Wanna know the same! And ofc I would be more then happy to re-use embedded fonts inf the PDF to create new Text with FPDI/FPDF so I do not have to blow the PDF-Filesize.. to bad I have not found any good solution to re-use embedded (not subsetting!) fonts..